# Why does my program not check the number of arguments correctly?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, binary-search-tree, stderr

Okay so I am writing code for a binary search tree that must read in strings from an input file: "input.txt" and I am trying to feed my program command line arguments. My program is supposed to take two command line args, the name of the program then the name of the file. I have an error check on it to stop the program if the number of args is not two. Why does my program still trip the error check when I run "./a.out main.c input.txt"?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 15

typedef struct treeNode{
  char string[MAXLEN+1];
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
}treeNode;

treeNode * insert(treeNode *node, char s[MAXLEN]){
  if(node == NULL){
    treeNode *temp;
    temp = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    strncpy(temp -> string, s, sizeof(treeNode));
    temp -> left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
  }

  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)>0){
    node -> right = insert(node->right, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s)<0){
    node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }
  else if(strcmp(node->string, s) == 0){
    node -> left = insert(node->left, s);
  }

}

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  treeNode *root = NULL;

  FILE *ifp;
  FILE *ofp;
  char s[MAXLEN+1];

  if(argc != 3){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[1]); exit(1);
  }

  if((ifp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file: %s\n", argv[2]); exit(1);
  }

  ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");

  fgets(s, MAXLEN, ifp);

  insert(root, s);

  fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", root->string);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `if(argc != 2)` to `if(argc != 3)`. The name of the program (`./a.out`) is also a parameter.

Comment: I've modified your question title to describe the actual problem.  The fact that it writes to stderr isn't relevant!

Comment: I just did and It is still tripping the error check. Thanks for the input though

Comment: Change `ifp = fopen(argv[1], "r")` to `ifp = fopen(argv[2], "r")`, since the name of the program is the first parameter, `input.txt` is the *third* parameter.

Comment: the returned values from fopen() and fgets() always need to be checked, not just 'sometimes'.  the function 'insert()' returns a parameter, but it is not being checked/utilized in the caller.

Comment: when using malloc() and family) 1) in C, the returned value should not be typecast.  2) the returned value should always be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: I'd like to know what book or tutorial you're using that does *not* describe how `argc` and `argv` work in a C program. Even the *worst* ones should do a sufficient job to avoid this, so whatever it is, it should be added to the avoid-at-all-costs list of lousy texts.

Comment: this line: 'strncpy(temp -> string, s, sizeof(treeNode));' is copying too much data I.E. it is copying past the end of the 's' buffer.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: 'strncpy(temp -> string, s, MAXLEN));'

Comment: regarding this line: 'insert(root, s);'  root is not updated (maybe the copied parameter in insert() is updated, but that does not update the 'root' seen in main().  suggest: 'root = insert(root, s);'

Comment: when the compiler handles the  'insert()' function, it will raise a flag, because the function has a return type 'treeNode *' but the lower 1/2 of the function does not return anything

Comment: these kind of recursive lines in the function insert() 'node -> right = insert(node->right, s);' will not update the receiving field (in this case node->right) because when some node already exists, the function insert() fails to return a value

Comment: suggest compiling with all warning flags enabled  Then fix the warnings

Comment: Thank you user3628249, your input really helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argc` will always be at least 1 because `argv[0]` contains the path to the executable.
Therefore you should be checking `if ( argc != 3 )` since you are passing 2 arguments from the command line.

When you execute `./a.out main.c input.txt`, `argv[1]` will be `main.c` and `argv[2]` will be `input.txt`.

You are off by 1 in many places when accessing the desired elements in the `argv` array, so make the appropriate changes.  Where you used `argv[1]`, you'll want to change it to `argv[2]`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I didn't think that a.out counted as an argument but it makes sense now. Though I changed the number of args to three, the error check is still being tripped

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I made the changes you are talking about I believe, but my error check is still getting tripped. As if the number of args is not 3?

Comment: @SamWylock  You didn't recompile.  I just copied, pasted, and ran your code.  It runs without printing any errors.

Comment: I was recompiling with the -c flag. removed the flag and it worked. Thank You!

Comment: @SamWylock Make sure to accept answers that helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @Daniel lol he's not coming back.  Kid got what he wanted and left like a 1 night stand.